# How to get the text attribute of a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am wondering how I can retrieve the text of the `selected` item in a `dropdown` using `JQuery`. Currently the code I have retrieves the `value` and I actually need the text associated with that `value`.

This is my code:

```
var stockCode = $(this).closest('li').find('.stock_code').html();
     var quantity = $(this).closest('li').find('.order_amount').val();
     var growers = $(this).closest('li').find('.growers').val();
     var sharequantity = $(this).closest('li').find('.share_amount').val();
```

This is `HTML`

```
    <span class="bulk" style="">
     <select name="CMP Member" id="CMP Member" class="growers">
        <option value="0">Choose Grower to Share...</option>
        <option value="10">xxxxx</option>
        <option value="25">xxxxx</option>
        <option value="4">xxxxxx</option>
        <option value="6">xxxxxx</option>
    </select>
```

I required the text at xxxxx...

Many thanks for any help. Also must point out I've got multiple `dropdowns` being generated dynamically so I would need to reference it by `class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get it by using the `:selected` selector along with the `.text()` function

```
 var growers = $(this).closest('li').find('.growers option:selcted').text();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `val()` for the option value attribute and `text()` for the text inside the option:

```
$(".growers option:selected").text();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.growers option:selected').text()
```